# latex in text citations error: citation undefined

Tags: latex, bibliography, biblatex

I am wanting to do in text citations for my dissertation. I will upload a simplified version of what i am seeing. The issue is that i keep getting "undefined citations" where i only get the citation key out in my pdf irrespective of which compiler i use.

I also keep getting an error saying that the bibliography is empty. But when my friend uses the exact code i have and copies the references and everything into his overleaf environment it works. I could not get it working with miktex and texmaker. Please help

I have checked a lot of articles of what is available and i swear im following what they are doing but i cant get any further

Initially, my idea is to pull the citations from another file because ill be using these citations in multiple documents. I have successfully setup the .bib file which will update as i add more references to Zotero (my reference manager). I tried to pull citations from the .bib file by coding in the file directory, but no luck there.

I then tried to not use the "file directory approach" and just have a references file in the same folder as the .tex file. But that didnt work either.

my code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib} %%updated from References.bib


%document headings
\title{Practice}
\author{Justin Smith}


\begin{document}
%Cover Page
\maketitle
\textbf{This page represents the cover page}\newline

\textit{Report will begin here}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagebreak


%Introduction
\section{Introduction}
The introduction for the report will be inserted here

\pagebreak
%end Introduction

%Literature Survey
\section{Literature Survey}
\subsection{Referencing Examples}
This section serves to use a reference and understand how to implement references as well as generate a reference list at the end of this report.\\

The citation test \cite{schmidtPreprocessingMethodologyEnhance2019}\\



\pagebreak
%Reference List
\section*{Reference List}
%%\bibliographystyle{IEEE}
%%\bibliography{C:/Users66smi/OneDrive/University of Pretoria/Zotero/MyZoteroLibrary.bib}

%%\printbibliography[title = Reference List]
%%\bibliography{MyZoteroLibrary.bib}

\end{document}
```

EDIT:
Upon trying to do what @celdor initially said said i still run into the same issue. The following screenshots add to the initial question.
[Screenshot showing code and issue directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLBbe.png)
[Screenshot showing Latex "Configure" settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wCzE.png)
[image: Warnings from Latex in Texmaker]

From the Log file, the following logs detail relevant warnings

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'schmidtPreprocessingMethodologyEnhance2019' on page 3 
undefined on input line 36.


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 36--37

 []

[3]

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 39.

(Latex test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                "Latex test"
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Package logreq Info: Writing requests to '"Latex test".run.xml'.
\openout1 = `"Latex test.run.xml"'.

 )
```

**Extra information:**
The following screenshots are of the Project folder

[image: Project Folder]
[image: Configuration 1]
[image: Configuration 2]
[image: Configuration 3]

Answer (score 3):

First, `latexsym` is an old package superseded by `amssymb`. I looked at the file and its last update was in 1998!

As to your issues, assuming your text file is `main.tex`, try the following:

- Clean your project folder from all auxiliary `*.aux`; the best way to do that is to issue `latexmk -C` in your project folder.
- Additionally, remove `main.bbl`
- make sure your `*.bib` file is in the root project folder
- add `backend=biber` to list of options of `biblatex`.

Then, run:

```bash
pdflatex main.tex     # or xelatex main.tex or lualatex main.tex etc.
biber main
pdflatex main.tex     # see above
```

Without `*.bbl` file, the first run of `pdflatex` does not produce any reference list and latex may issue a warning. With an old `*.bbl` file, you will get wrong citations. After the whole sequence is executed, `main.pdf` should have the correct citation and a reference list.

Remember `\bibliography` is incompatible with `biblatex`. The correct macro to create bibliography list is `\printbibliography`. It will issue `\section*` in `article` or `\chapter*` in `report`/`book` for a title and format it according to settings in a document class.

Here, I created `References.bib` with a dummy article:

```latex
@ARTICLE{schmidtPreprocessingMethodologyEnhance2019,
  author  = {Other, Anthony Norman},
  title   = {Some things I did},
  year    = {2014},
  journal = {J.~Irrep. Res.},
  volume  = {1},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {1-10}
}
```

and run the code as suggested, and frankly I get expected results without any errors!

The full code:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}   %superseds latexsym   
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}


%document headings
\title{Practice}
\author{Justin Smith}


\begin{document}
%Cover Page
\maketitle
\textbf{This page represents the cover page}\newline

\textit{Report will begin here}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagebreak


%Introduction
\section{Introduction}
The introduction for the report will be inserted here

\pagebreak
%end Introduction

%Literature Survey
\section{Literature Survey}
\subsection{Referencing Examples}
This section serves to use a reference and understand how to implement references as well as generate a reference list at the end of this report.\\

The citation test \cite{schmidtPreprocessingMethodologyEnhance2019}\\

\clearpage
\printbibliography[title = Reference List]
\end{document}
```

and here's the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please see the answer i attached detailing the prevailing issue

Comment: You need to make sure your editor is correctly setup. From the screenshots, you indeed run a sequence of commands as you are supposed to. I don't use TexMaker and have no idea what the settings should be. Perhaps share your `test.log` (in question). It contains all the information you need. Look for lines starting with an exclamation mark `!` as well as any `Warning`, e.g. `Resources.bib not available` as you are probably not loading the file!

Comment: Hi, im not sure what you mean with lines starting with ! or warning. I have updated the question as best as i can. But it seems there arent warnings which are new other than what i described origionally

Comment: I have added all warnings pertaining to the issues im facing from the log file. Please tell me if those are correct?

Comment: Would you be able to compile this file in command line as I suggested in my answer? Also, Overleaf might be a good idea to try to load this MWE in Overleaf.

Comment: i am really struggling to understand how to do that? Hence i initially deleted all the files through an equivalent method. Im not actually sure what you are wanting?

Comment: FYI overleaf was the enviroment a friend of mine got this code to run in successfully. However, moving to overleaf does not solve my issue

Comment: Just one more thing. Perhaps rename `Resources.bib` to lower case: `resources.bib` and change `\addbibresources` to `\addbibresource{resources.bib}` in your `tex` file. Then, make sure you clean your project folder from `aux` and `bbl` files before you run compilation and see if that works.

Comment: I did that now. No difference

Comment: If you get undefined citation, it means your file `Resources.bib` is not seen by LaTeX, cannot be loaded and then latex can't produces citation nor can it produce bibliography, hence the warning "Empty biliography". It might be biber cannot find bbl file as well.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your project folders? and perhaps your settings? I doubt I can help you with that but there might see something obvious.

Comment: This has been the issue going this whole time? Im still not sure what more to do? Surely there is a simple solution for this since its a basic task. I have tried playing in the texmaker configuration settings and still no luck

Comment: LaTeX cannot find your file `Resources.bib`. It might be that `test.bbl` produced by LaTeX on first compilation is being moved to another folder and `biber` cannot find it. Are you sure all the files are in the root project folder? Can you show a structure of your project?

Comment: im 100% sure all the files are in the same root folder. I did attach a screenshot

Comment: There's no such file as `Resources.bib` in that folder. There is `refs.bib`, though. Either rename `refs.bib` to `Resources.bib` or change `\addbibresource` to `\addbibresource{refs.bib}` in your tex file and see if that helps.

Comment: i updated the screenshots of the tex file a while ago so everything is consistent to refs.bib. So the issue is still present as there wasnt a file path error

Comment: LaTeX is searching your project folder for `References.bib` via `\addbibresource{References.bib}` and your screenshot shows there's no such file. There is `refs.bib` but this is not the file LaTeX is trying to read.

Comment: yes. my code (typed out) shows that its references but i updated it now. that was the *old* code. the actual screenshots reflect otherwise

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you, then. For some reason, `biblatex` cannot find the definition of that article and therefore cannot produce the bibliography. Usually, the problem is either with wrong file names or typos in reference IDs. Sometimes using simple file names without spaces helps. In your case everything seems to be in place. Since I don't know TeXMaker at all, I cannot really provide any further help. Good luck.

Comment: thank you for your efforts. i would appreciate an boost on this post so i may find a resolution. I did double check now your code does run in my overleaf enviroment just fine. its when its in the textmaker its an issue

Comment: @JustinSmith Your screenshot shows that you configured texmaker to use bibtex, but with biblatex, you need to use `biber` instead of bibtex

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, please explain where i do that. I could not find the option to use biber...?
Im not sure where to add that on texmaker, but it seems when i moved to texstudio and applied the setting you are correct!

thank you for the assistance

Comment: @JustinSmith If it works with texstudio, just keep using this. Texstudio started out as a texmaker fork, but got some nice features a long the way - I'm sure it will do you good service in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The answer as suggested by @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
is that I was not using biber.

To do this on textmaker proceed to Options/Configure Textmaker. A configuration window will appear. Under the Commands Window locate "Bib(la)tex" and set the designation to "biber %". This will solve the issue.

[Setting Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGKgm.png)

A similar procedure can be followed on texstudios

See the below link on how to make sure textmaker uses this setting for reference.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44040/biblatex-biber-texmaker-miktex

thank you for everyones efforts in solving this problem.